# X-Superobject, несовпадение типов данных при запросе строки

Tags: json, delphi

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании X-SuperObject.

Есть JSON вида:

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Василий",
    "sk":[{
        "type": "public",
        "time": "2"
    }]  
  },
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Алексей",
    "sk":[{
        "type": "private",
        "time": "12"
    }]  
  },
{
    "id":3,
    "name":"Семён",
    "sk":[{
        "type": "public",
        "time": "1"
    }]  
  },
  .....
]
```

При попытке запросить какой-либо элемент, как строку:

```
var x,z: ISuperObject;
var a: ISuperArray;
i:integer;
begin
  x := SO(RichEdit1.Text);
  a:=x.A['personal'];
  for i := 0 to a.Length-1 do
  begin

    memo2.Lines.add(a.A[i].S['name']);
  end;
```

Компиллятор ругается на `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(398): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'string'` В строке `memo2.Lines.add(a.A[i].S['name']);`.

В чем может быть проблема? Вроде бы как методы выбраны верно.

Comment: Проверьте плиз, выглядит как двойное обращение к массиву - `add(a.A[i].S` точно так, а не `add(a[i].S`?

Comment: @Kromster, не помогло: `[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(398): E2149 Class does not have a default property`

Comment: @Kromster , как я понял - проблема в несоответствии типов. Почему -то при попытке запросить строку `.S['name']` просить integer.

Comment: а не какой нибудь там `a.O[i].S['name']`  нужен?

Comment: зы: таки ругается то он по моему на `a.A[i]` а не на `.s['name']`

Comment: @teran , странная история какая то получается. `property S:[V:Integer]:string;` в коде библиотеки такая вот история есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя пару часов мозгового штурма и добавленной щепоточки внимательности все переписано на следующий вариант с простым SuperObject:

```
var x,z: ISuperObject;
n:string;
begin

  z:= SO(RichEdit3.Text);
  showmessage(z['1'].S['name']);

end;
```

Ларчик просто открывался. Как вывод - нечего городить велосипеды.